# Magento2 Apis fectching product collection in entry.php file

Tags: magento2, api

Can anyone help me, how this content for apis is actually fetching and how the collection is getting here for the below file:

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/Entry.php

Screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/i3rq6u

Actually the above api screenshot content is comming from below function in Entry.php file:

```
public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::FILE);
    }
```

How the content is loading here.

Thanks

Comment: You can check it inside entry.php file they have setFile() functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rakesh, i have seen like in set file function:$this->setData(self::FILE, $file);

Comment: how the collection is fetching here actually